# many-to-many query runs slow in windows phone 7 emulator

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-7, many-to-many

my application is using sqlite for a database. in the database, i have a many-to-many relationship. when i use the sqlite addon/tool for firefox, the sql query joining the tables in the many-to-many runs pretty fast. however, when i run the same query on the emulator, it takes a very long time (5 minutes or more). i haven't even tried it on a real device, thus.

can someone tell me what is going on?

for example, i have 3 table.
1. create table person (id integer, name text);
2. create table course (id integer, name text);
3. create table registration(personId integer, courseId integer);

my sql statements that i have tried are as follows.

```
select * 
from person, course, registration
where registration.personId = person.id and registration.courseId = course.id
```

and also as follows.

```
select *
from person inner join registration on person.id=registration.personId
inner join course on course.id=registration.courseId
```

i am using the sqlite client from http://wp7sqlite.codeplex.com. i have 4,800 records in the registration table, 4,000 records in the person table, and 1,000 records in the course table.

is it my queries? is it just the sqlite client? is it the record size? if this problem cannot be fixed on the app, i'm afraid i'll have to push the database remotely (that means my app will have to use the internet).

Answer (score 2):

Yep, its your queries.  You're not going to get away with you can get away with doing what you are trying to do on a mobile device.  You have to remember you aren't running on a PC so you have to think differently about how you approach things (both code and UI). You have low memory, slow disk access, a slow-ish processor, no virtual memory, etc. You're going to have to make compromises.

I'm sure what ever you are doing is perfectly possible to do on the phone without needing an offsite server but you need to be smart about it.  For example is it really necessary to load all 4800+ records into memory at once?  Almost certainly not, a user can't possibly at look at all 4800 at the same time.  Forgetting the database speed just showing this number of items in a ListBox is going to kill your app performance wise.

And even is performance was perfect is displaying 4800 items really a good user experience?  Surely allowing the user to enter a search term would be better and would allow you to filter the list to a more manageable size.  Could you implement paging so you only display the first 10 records and have the user click next for the next 10?

You might also want to consider de-normalizing your database, so that you just have one table rather than 3.  It will improve performance considerably.  Yes it goes against everything you were taught about databases in school but like I said: phone = compromises.  And remember this isn't a big OLTP mission critical database, its a phone app - no one cares if your database is in 3rd normal form or not.  Also remember that the more work you give the phone (chugging through data building up joins) the more battery power you app will consume.

Finally if you absolutely think you must to give the user a list of 4800 records to scroll through, you should look at some kind of data virtualization technique.  Which gives the user the illusion they are scrolling through a long list, even though there are actually only a few items loaded at any given time.

But the short answer is: yes, doing queries like that will problematic, you need to consider changing them.

Comment: my example queries above are not exactly like the ones i am using; the only difference being is that on my app, i do implement a filter (i.e. where clause). however, that still doesn't solve the performance issue. i don't load all 4800 at once. my UI currently uses a Pivot, and each PivotItem is simply A, B, ..., Z. when the user clicks on A, B, ..., Z, then i fetch the correct rows. i might consider denormalizing as you stated (merge all 3 into one), but  denormalization might improve performance, but at the expense of space requirements.

Comment: never heard of data virtualization technique. i will search that on the internet (sounds similar to lazy loading). if you have a link please let me know. for this technique, if a user scrolls through a long list, what happens to the data that is out of view? is it gone (out from the memory)?

Comment: lastly, i'm using sqlite, as stated, and i tried to compress the sqlite file (i.e. using the vacuum command) but it doesn't really compress. as far as i understand, you can define a number of string field data types, but eventually, they are stored as TEXT type; i wonder if this contributes to the size growth (it certainly does on other databases). my thought is, will Mango and the introduction of native database support via SQL Compact do anything for data compression? or is this something left entirely to the developers? just wondering if it's worth downloading the beta SDK.

Comment: No SQL Compact on WP7 doesn't compress as such, and indeed you wouldn't want it to.  You'd trading CPU cycles (for decompression\compression) for smaller disk space.  You really want to be doing the exact opposite on a small device like this were processor cycles are at a premium

Answer (score 1):

By the time you start doing those joins that's an awfuly large amount of records you could end up with. What is memory like during this operation?

Assuming you have tuned indexes appropraitely, rather than do this with joins, I'd try three separate queries.

Either that or consider restructuring your data so it only contains what you need in the app.
You should also look to only return the fields you need.

Comment: the sqlite db file is itself 18 MB already. if i add the proper indexes, the sqlite file blows up to 50 MB. i searched on the internet, and it seems a WP7 app's size limit is 2 GB, but still, i highly doubt that users want to download an app such as mine at 50 MB or even 18 MB. imo, most large sized apps are gaming apps, and users will probably only tolerate such sizes if they are for entertainment (and my app is not). i haven't profiled memory usage yet, and so i can't answer you on that point.

Comment: based on your response, it's looking like i keep the database on the internet and force users to load/save data remotely.

Comment: Accessing thousands of non-indexed rows sounds like the biggest cause of issues. If you really want to keep the size small then putting the DB on a web server sounds like a plan.